# How to display ad one on the right and one on the left?

Tags: html, css

We wish to place both adsense ad 780x90 and custom image ad 400x90 in the same row ie. one on the right and one on the left.

[image: snapshot]

my css

```
.topadleft{
    float:left; 
}
.topadright{
    float:right;
}
.topadwrap{
    padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;
    background-color:#f0f0f0;

}
```

my html

```
<div class="topadwrap">
<div class="topadleft">
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
 style="display:block"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-######"
 data-ad-slot="9425714545"
 data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
</div>
<div class="topadright">
 <a href="#" target="_blank" border="0"><img src="images/ad.jpg"></a>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  Can you make a fiddle and describe what's not working and what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `float` both ads `left`and just add a `.right` class to the smaller one to adjust the space between them.

Also, make sure you close your `div` elements (your `.topadright` is open), and if you aren't going to give a height to the container you should add a `.clearfix` to it so that it clears the ads.

I have made a sample below - but replaced your google ad with an image.

```css
.topad{
  float:left; 
}
.right{
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.topadwrap{
  padding:10px;
  background-color:#f0f0f0;
}
.clearfix:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="topadwrap clearfix">
<div class="topad left">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/780x90 ">
</div>
<div class="topad right">
   <a href="#" target="_blank" border="0"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x90"></a>
</div>
```

Hope that fixes your issue.

**EDIT:**

Responsive AdSense requires you to add a width/height to the parent element - `width: auto;` is not accepted... so you need to specify the `width` and `height` of the containing div. Then use media queries to modify the size of the ad served into the parent container for different browser/device sizes.

[AdSense Reference](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3213689?hl=en)

I took a look at your URL and mocked up a [quick pen](http://codepen.io/matthewelsom/pen/KpgEmy) with some responsive queries based on your site showing you how the width and height of the ads could be adapted.

Hope that's a fix that works for you!

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
.topad{
  float:left; 
  width: 780px;
  height: 90px;
}
.left {
  background: lightpink;
}
.right{
  float: right;
  width: 400px;
  height: 90px;
}
.topadwrap{
  padding:10px 0;
  background-color:#f0f0f0;
  width: 1233px;
  margin: auto;
}
.clearfix:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1233px) {
  .topadwrap{
    width: 960px;
  }
  .left{
    width: 520px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .topadwrap{
    width: 800px;
  }
  .left{
    width: 400px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .topadwrap{
    width: 100%;
  }
  .topad{
    width: 100%;
  }
  .right {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topadwrap clearfix">
<div class="topad left"></div>
  <div class="topad right">
 <a href="#" target="_blank" border="0"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x90"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanx for your reply. But responsive adsense code not support for this code. Adsense ad not showing. Any idea?

Comment: Do you have a URL so I can take a look at a live sample?

Comment: yes, kindly view http://tamilchristianradio.com/evangel-fm/

Comment: I have updated my answer... you need to specify widths for the AdSense parent container at each of your breakpoints... `width: auto;` is not accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Set `float: left` for both

```
<div class="topadwrap">
  <div class="topadleft"> 
    <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-######" data-ad-slot="9425714545" data-ad-format="auto">
    </ins>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/700x100" />
  </div>
  <div class="topadright"> <a href="#" target="_blank" border="0"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.topadleft {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
}

.topadright {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 2%;
  width: auto;
}

.topadwrap {
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

[**Jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/7pryed32/4/embedded/result/)

Comment: Thanx for your reply. But responsive adsense code not support for this code. Adsense ad not showing. Any idea? view http://tamilchristianradio.com/kross-fm/